# How crop and scale a video programmatically without ffmpeg

Tags: android

i would like to crop and scale a recorded video without the use of ffmpeg, is there any way?

I would avoid to use ffmpeg to not have compatibility problems.

Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

Ummm... try to use gstreamer instead of ffmpeg. BTW, what is wrong with ffmpeg?

For example, this is gstreamer conveyor

```
gst-launch v4l2src ! video/x-raw-yuv,width=640,height=480,framerate=15/1 ! aspectratiocrop aspect-ratio=16/9 ! \ ffmpegcolorspace ! xvimagesink
```

It takes video from the webcam, changes aspect, then shows output to user.

Comment: Only to not have compatibility problems.

Comment: @alfdev So... what about gstreamer?

Comment: @gbg i never used it.